# No visible @interface for AVCamViewController declares the selector layer

Tags: interface, selector, layer, avcam

```
- (void)setSession:(AVCaptureSession *)session {
    ((AVPlayerLayer *)[self layer]).videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill;
    ((AVPlayerLayer *)[self layer]).bounds = ((AVPlayerLayer *)[self layer]).bounds;
    [(AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer *)[self layer] setSession:session];
}
```

When I try to use the videogravity code, it shows the error, `No visible @interface for AVCamViewController` declares the selector layer, on the three bottom lines when it says "self layer" in the AVCAM sample? How do I fix this?